# querying a one to many realtion where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with three tables

- Products
- Fieldnames
- Field values

Products:

- ID
- Name

Fieldnames:

- NameID
- DisplayName

Field values

- ProductID
- NameID
- FieldValue

I am trying to get all products where the date in the field with the name 'start' is earlier then today and the date in the field 'end' is later then today.

My current solution:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Product
WHERE  (SELECT FieldValue 
        FROM FieldValues
        WHERE NameID = ( SELECT NameID 
                        FROM Fieldnames
                        WHERE DisplayName = 'start')) < today
AND (SELECT FieldValue 
        FROM FieldValues
        WHERE NameID = ( SELECT NameID 
                        FROM Fieldnames
                        WHERE DisplayName = 'end')) > today
```

Where today is filled in by c# code.
But this does not return the desired output. What am I missing ?

Comment: did you forget the question?

Comment: The field in `Fieldnames` is `DisplayName` or `DisplayValue`?

Comment: Can a Product have a start but no end or an end but no start?

Comment: @toonice No that is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ...

```
SELECT ID
FROM Products, FieldNames, FieldValues
WHERE FieldValues.ProductID = Products.ID AND
      FieldValues.NameID = FieldNames.NameID AND
      ( ( DisplayName = "start" AND FieldValue < today ) OR
        ( DisplayName = "end" AND FieldValue > today ) );
```

Without test data I can not test this out, and fortunately enough time has become available for me to do so.  In the future, if you post script for creating the tables and populating them with test data we can check our answers for any bugs.

Firstly I shall explain the reasoning behind my answer, after which I shall list the script I used to test with.

I started with -

```
SELECT *
FROM Products, FieldNames, FieldValues
WHERE FieldValues.ProductID = Products.ID AND
      FieldValues.NameID = FieldNames.NameID
```

I used `SELECT *` rather than `SELECT ID` here so I could examine the data to determine if I was getting accurate results.  It works just as well either way.

I used `FROM Products, FieldNames, FieldValues` rather than just `FROM Products` since we are referencing all three tables in the `WHERE` clause even though we are returning just the ID's.  I tried it with just `FROM Products` - it complained (and didn't work).

I added -

```
WHERE FieldValues.ProductID = Products.ID AND
      FieldValues.NameID = FieldNames.NameID
```

to join the tables, which was made necessary by the fact that FieldName and FieldValue are in separate tables.  I included a join to Products as well just in case you wish to return any other fields from there in addition to ID.  If you only wish to return ID, then you should change the first four lines to -

```
SELECT *
FROM FieldNames, FieldValues
WHERE FieldValues.NameID = FieldNames.NameID
```

Either way , to refine the search to only valid results I added -

```
      ( ( DisplayName = "start" AND FieldValue < today ) OR
        ( DisplayName = "end" AND FieldValue > today ) );
```

The outermost brackets are necessary, otherwise the OR could muck with the joining clause.  Even if it wouldn't, it's a nice way of isolating our out-of-range argument.

Similarly, the innermost brackets help preserve the (start, <) and (end, >) conditions.

I tested the final statement by substituting `45` for `value`, a la -

```
SELECT ID
FROM Products, FieldNames, FieldValues
WHERE FieldValues.ProductID = Products.ID AND
      FieldValues.NameID = FieldNames.NameID AND
      ( ( DisplayName = "start" AND FieldValue < 45 ) OR
        ( DisplayName = "end" AND FieldValue > 45 ) );
```

The results were as desired.

The following is the script I used to create and populate the tables...

```
CREATE DATABASE Products20151020;

USE Products20151020;

CREATE TABLE Products
(
    ID      INT              NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name    VARCHAR( 50 )    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( ID )
);

CREATE TABLE FieldNames
(
    NameID         INT              NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DisplayName    VARCHAR( 50 )    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( NameID )
);

CREATE TABLE FieldValues
(
    fldID         INT    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ProductID     INT    NOT NULL,
    NameID        INT    NOT NULL,
    FieldValue    INT    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( fldID ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( ProductID )    REFERENCES Products( ID ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( NameID )       REFERENCES FieldNames( NameID )
);

INSERT INTO Products
SET Name = "Name 001";

INSERT INTO Products
SET Name = "Name 002";

INSERT INTO Products
SET Name = "Name 003";

INSERT INTO Products
SET Name = "Name 004";

INSERT INTO Products
SET Name = "Name 005";

INSERT INTO Products
SET Name = "Name 006";

INSERT INTO Products
SET Name = "Name 007";

INSERT INTO Products
SET Name = "Name 008";

INSERT INTO Products
SET Name = "Name 009";

INSERT INTO Products
SET Name = "Name 010";

INSERT INTO FieldNames
SET DisplayName = "start";

INSERT INTO FieldNames
SET DisplayName = "end";

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 1,
    NameID     = 1,
    FieldValue = 26;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 5,
    NameID     = 1,
    FieldValue = 46;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 3,
    NameID     = 1,
    FieldValue = 45;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 7,
    NameID     = 1,
    FieldValue = 44;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 10,
    NameID     = 1,
    FieldValue = 100;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 8,
    NameID     = 1,
    FieldValue = 10;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 9,
    NameID     = 1,
    FieldValue = 32;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 2,
    NameID     = 1,
    FieldValue = 99;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 10,
    NameID     = 2,
    FieldValue = 26;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 9,
    NameID     = 2,
    FieldValue = 46;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 7,
    NameID     = 2,
    FieldValue = 45;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 6,
    NameID     = 2,
    FieldValue = 44;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 4,
    NameID     = 2,
    FieldValue = 100;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 3,
    NameID     = 2,
    FieldValue = 10;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 1,
    NameID     = 2,
    FieldValue = 32;

INSERT INTO FieldValues
SET ProductID  = 2,
    NameID     = 2,
    FieldValue = 99;
```

If anyone has any questions or general comments, then please feel free to post a comment.

Comment: Hello toonice great work with the sample, but maybe you didnt know [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/077308/7)?  Anyway I prepare it for you  to help show the results. I change your `SELECT ID` to `SELECT *`, You will see `product_id = 9` is the only one with `start < 45 and end > 45`  all other `product_id` only match one side, that is why  @colmde  has the right answer.

Comment: I appreciate the comment.  Please see my reply on the relevant question.

Comment: btw you shouldnt downvote for one spell error. Also that answer work exactly as OP request with `AND` for both dates. Even when you read OP sample query you realize he already was going for a similar route. I understand lenguaje can be interpreted on different ways, But in that case the fault should be on OP question not @colmde answer so he doesnt deserve a downvote.

Comment: The downvote was based on the other point mentioned (again, apologies - downvote cancelled).  The spelling error wouldn't have been worth mentioning in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM Product p
JOIN FieldValues fv on p.id = fv.productid
JOIN Fieldnames fn on fn.nameid = fv.nameid
WHERE 
    (DisplayName = 'start' and fv.FieldValue < today)
OR (DisplayName = 'end' and fv.FieldValue > today)
```

Comment: I just realize. Need to make double join. because you need both field `start `and `end`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza..i don't think it is needed in this case, as the column being `select`ed is from the `product` table

Comment: `DisplayName` cant equal 'start' and 'end' at the same time.

Comment: @Octopi..i had `or` before @JuanCarlosOropeza edited it

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake with the `OR/AND` that is when I realize that current query doesnt solve the problem and I make the comment. You need a product with both condition `start < time AND end > time` currently If one is true you still return the `product_id`

Comment: Maybe adding a `group by p.ID  having count(*) = 2` will solve that problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to link the Fieldvalues.ProductID back to the Product.ID.

```
SELECT ID 
FROM Products p 
WHERE (SELECT fv.FieldValue 
       FROM FieldValues fv JOIN Fieldnames fn ON fv.NameID = fn.NameID
       WHERE fv.ProductID = p.ID AND fn.DisplayName = 'start') < today   
  AND (SELECT fv.FieldValue 
       FROM FieldValues fv JOIN Fieldnames fn ON fv.NameID = fn.NameID
       WHERE fv.ProductID = p.ID AND fn.DisplayName = 'end') > today
```

Comment: I have down voted because (a) the name of the table given by the Questioner is Products, not Product (note the plural), and (b) when I changed the outermost FROM line to "FROM Products p, FieldNames, FieldValues", and tested it as per the data in my answer all I got was a bunch of 9's.

Comment: @toonice Did you miss some text after `because` ?

Comment: Sorry - still getting used to the fact that you have to cram all of your comment into a single line.

Comment: My apologies - I have interpreted the Question to mean a Product can have a start, but not yet an end.  There are also possible circumstances where a Product might have no recorded start but a recorded end.  I am hoping for clarification from the Questioner on this point, but based my answer on the interpretation just stated.  If both a start and an end is required, and the answer is edited to correct points (a) and (b) from above, then I will be happy to cancel the downvote.

Comment: @toonice I fix the `products` spell error, but this query doesnt need cross join with `FieldValues` or `Fieldnames` OP result require only the `product_id`

Comment: You are correct - I have retested and it works as you say..  I do apologise, and can only say that perhaps I should not try combining a cold and insomnia with testing code.  :). I shall cancel the downvote.